# how does java bean encapsulate many objects into one

Tags: javabeans

in definition it is said "java bean encapsulates many objects into one object(Bean). what does "many objects" here mean and how they are encapsulated into one object by java beans?

Comment: Wow, I'm amazed this question remains unanswered!

Comment: now, answer is here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60436733/java-bean-encapsulates-many-objects-into-one-how