# Java Bean encapsulates many objects into one,How?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I'm newly started reading about Java Beans and I had a question which was exactly same as this [Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117896/how-does-java-bean-encapsulate-many-objects-into-one)'s question. So I repeat The question:

in definition it is said "**java bean encapsulates many objects into one object(Bean).**"

> 1.What does "many objects" here mean?

and

> 2.How they are encapsulated into one object by java beans?

---

**Edit:**

From [Java Beans Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans):

> in computing based on the Java Platform, JavaBeans are classes that encapsulate many objects into a single object (the bean).

---

**Edit2:**
all of classes have ability of having multiple attributes and fields.
If encapsulating of many objects means having multiple attributes and fields, I don't understand why they mentioned to this ability as a advantage of java bean class.

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: @Nexevis From This: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First to make it clear, every `Class` in Java extends the type `Object`.  Something like `String` is also an `Object`.

The "many objects" is referring to how we can use different objects as fields within the bean.  This creates a **has-a** relationship with the bean to your `Objects`.

For example, say we have this `Bean`:

```
public class YourBean implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String s;
    private ArrayList<String> list;

    //Omitted rest of bean boilerplate
}
```

This example will contain two different `Object`s inside of it, the `String s` and the `ArrayList<String>` named `list`.  You can add as many different `Objects` and primitives to your bean as you want.

To create the bean with a no-args constructor, you would then use:

```
YourBean bean = new YourBean();
```

And you can set and get the values of the `Objects` encapsulated within with:

```
ArrayList<String> yourList = new ArrayList<>();
bean.setList(yourList);
System.out.println(bean.getList());
```

You will be able to refer to all the `Objects` inside the bean this way by referencing the bean `Object` I named `bean`.

Additionally, you can create multiple of the same type of `bean` as well, so every time you make a `new YourBean()`, you will also be able to use all the `Objects` contained within.

This functionality is not unique to a `Bean`, you can do this in any `Class`, rather a `Bean` is a term used to describe a specific way you write some classes.

I recommend looking into **Java Composition** to learn when you should use a **has-a** relationship, rather than **inheritance** which is an **is-a** relationship.

Comment: Thank u very much for explaining. Of course all of classes have this ability, but I don't understand why they mentioned to this ability as a advantage of bean.

Comment: @Meh Sar It does not necessarily call it an _adavantage_, the wikipedia is explaining that is what a bean _is_.  If you don't have any class fields, it isn't a bean.  A bean is just a term for a specific type of class you can write.  It says  "JavaBeans **are** classes that encapsulate many objects into a single object (the bean)".  Even under the advantages list in the wikipedia article you linked, it does not write multiple objects as one.

Answer (score 2):

We usually talk about Spring beans, but I think that's not what you're talking about. It seems to me that those JavaBeans are nothing but classes with multiple attributes and only getters/setters but whose constructor has zero arguments (and therefore it is mutable). As simple as that. The fact of encapsulating many objects is due to it having multiple attributes.

However, I have never referred to them as JavaBeans and I think the most similar concept I have ever worked with are the POJOs. I'm not sure if there is any difference, but the purpose looks the same.

If you ever talk about a bean in Java, I think anyone will think of a [Spring bean](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean). I suggest you not to use it in another context.

This is just my guessing. If I've said anything wrong please tell me.

Comment: Thank u very much for explaining. Of course all of classes have this ability(having multiple attributes), but I don't understand why they mentioned to this ability as a advantage of bean

Comment: I think it's because they are explaining beans as a pattern. In this case, the encapsulation is its main feature. Any class can make use of it (and they do), but in beans the focus is on the encapsulation. I think that's why.

Answer (score 2):

**JAVA Beans**

The concept of JavaBeans was originally devised for Swing to facilitate the development of standalone GUI components, but the pattern has been repurposed for the land of Spring beans and back-end persistence with Hibernate

On the other hand, **POJOs** are simple java classes.

---

Another View:

*Any POJO on having interaction with some third party become JAVA BEAN :)*

- Java Classes interacting with any ORM(say Hibernate)
- Java Classes being used as Session Objects in EJB

As they say, *"With Great Powers Comes Great Responsibilities"* [excerpt from spiderman]

So our normal Pojos become JAVA BEANS :)

An article worth going through: https://mossgreen.github.io/Java-Bean-VS-Spring-Bean/